# How to use Phalanger to obfuscate php code on CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, obfuscation, phalanger

I have been working on PHP application built using CodeIgniter framework, which needs to be deployed on client site. I want to protect php code by compiling it before deployment using Phalanger. For testing this I've created a demo project on CodeIgniter with just one function and controller. Now I just need to protect the controller/method I've created on the top of CodeIgniter while leaving rest of CodeIgniter as it is. I have tried several ways and also tried to find how to do it on google, but there isn't any good material on how to use Phalanger. Does any one had any success using Phalanger to obfuscate php code for deployment?  Any tutorial or help will be good. Thanks

Comment: I know it doesn't help you, but I work for a company that uses Phalanger in production for very large clients, with great success. (Not for obfuscation, but because the client for some strange reason doesn't want to use a **real** server operating system :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phalanger allows compilation of PHP scripts into [Multi Script Assemblies](http://wiki.php-compiler.net/Multi_Script_Assembly). However full obfuscation of generated DLL is a part of proprietary Phalanger extension which can be obtained from [DEVSENSE support](http://www.devsense.com/services/phalanger).

Comment: The docs say `In PHP project
Simply setup your script library as it is described above and use standard include statement to include scripts from script library. Note scripts in script libraries has priority over scripts on file system.` 
   `include 'file.php';` I have generated a dll file. Now how do I add the phalenger runtime for web projects for php? Or do I use this as a PHP extension in php.ini http://wiki.php-compiler.net/Multi_Script_Assembly#In_PHP_project